# Get value from object or convert to array for get url of monolog log on Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, object, laravel-5

I need get property of log name on my Laravel app.

I get with and array with a object with method:

```
$arr =  Log::getMonolog()->getHandlers();
dd($arr);
```

Result

```
array:1 [
  0 => Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler {#43
    #filename: "/Users/abkrim/desarrollos/cprsync_v3/storage/logs/cprsync.log"
    ..
    #url: "/Users/abkrim/desarrollos/cprsync_v3/storage/logs/cprsync-2017-01-06.log"
    ...
    #processors: []
  }
]
```

Also try

```
$arr =  (array) Log::getMonolog()->getHandlers()[0];
dd($arr)
```

But I get and array with wrong key values.

```
array:16 [
  "\x00*\x00filename" => "/Users/abkrim/desarrollos/cprsync_v3/storage/logs/cprsync.log"
  "\x00*\x00maxFiles" => 5
  "\x00*\x00mustRotate" => null
  "\x00*\x00nextRotation" => DateTime {#41
    +"date": "2017-01-07 00:00:00.000000"
    +"timezone_type": 3
    +"timezone": "Europe/Madrid"
  }
  "\x00*\x00filenameFormat" => "{filename}-{date}"
  "\x00*\x00dateFormat" => "Y-m-d"
  "\x00*\x00stream" => null
  "\x00*\x00url" => "/Users/abkrim/desarrollos/cprsync_v3/storage/logs/cprsync-2017-01-06.log"
  "\x00Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler\x00errorMessage" => null
  "\x00*\x00filePermission" => null
```

I need access to value `url`, and I try with array conversion, get_object_vars... but any work.

Obviously i can access with code below, but I think, that way it's not correct or the best way

```
$arr["\x00*\x00url"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `getUrl()` function of `Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler` class since `RotatingFileHandler` extends the class. Try following

```
Log::getMonolog()->getHandlers()[0]->getUrl()
```

Note - This only works for `APP_LOG` `daily` value

Comment: I thought I had tried that road, because it seemed the most logical.A lot of thanks